# What is performance of ContainsKey and TryGetValue?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, big-o

I'm prepping for interviews, and some obvious interview questions such as counting frequency of characters in a string involve putting all of the characters into a Hashtable/Dictionary in order to get O(n) runtime for the algorithm.  My question is, what is the performance hit by using `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue` to check to see if a key has already been inserted into the Hashtable?  Can I still have an O(n) algorithm for problems like these that use `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming a good hash without too many collisions, each of those are O(1) operations.

As for how those operations work... I suggest you read up on [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: @alexD -- remember, it's O(1) in the optimal case.  A hashtable with the world's worst hashing algorithm will put every item in a single linked-list bucket or similar, and approach O(N) as it sorts through the duplicates. :)

Comment: TryGetValue seems to be quicker as ContainsKey requires two hash lookups for a match - the test then the retrieval.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I'd expect it to be quicker - but not in terms of algorithmic complexity, where constant factors aren't important.